# How does error handling work when you use Invoke-Command over several computers?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

How does error handling work when I use `Invoke-Command` over many computers?  For example, what if a computer name is misspelled or the user doesn't exist on a specific computer?

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer1,Computer2,Computer3  -ScriptBlock {        
    Get-LocalUser -Name User1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
}
```

Comment: From the docs: `Errors that result from the command that Invoke-Command runs are included in the command results.`

Comment: Taking out "-erroraction silentlycontinue" would help.

Comment: OP is asking about handling of `Invoke-Command` not `Get-LocalUser` @js2010

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`-ErrorVariable` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.3#-errorvariable) for this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer1, Computer2, doesNotexist -ScriptBlock {        
    Get-LocalUser -Name User1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable errors

# error details here
$errors | Select-Object TargetObject, ErrorDetails
```