# How do I show progress for each computer where the password was changed successfully

Tags: powershell

Given:
PowerShell 5.1
Azure DevOps 2020
Windows Server 2016 Standard

Is there a way I can output message for each computer that successfully updates the LocalUser?

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer1,Computer2 -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'P@$$w0rd123' -AsPlainText -Force
    Set-LocalUser -Name User1 -Password $securePassword -Verbose
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the cmdlet produces [no output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/set-localuser?view=powershell-5.1#outputs) you can use a [`Try Catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.3) statement:

```bash
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer1,Computer2 -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'P@$$w0rd123' -AsPlainText -Force

    try {
        Set-LocalUser -Name User1 -Password $securePassword -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
        $status = 'Success'
    }
    catch {
        $status = 'Fail'
        $errmsg = $_.Exception.Message
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        Status   = $status
        Error    = $errmsg
    }
} -HideComputerName | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceId
```

Comment: I noticed that as soon as one of the computers fail the following computers after that do not get set as well. Is there a way that if one computer fails to update to continue setting password for the rest of the computers remaining?

Comment: @Rod are you using the error preference as shown in [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75558452/15339544) for `Invoke-Command` ? If the preference is `Stop` then as soon as you cant connect to one of the computers the command will stop, as the name implies.